# SQL select multiple columns according to current month

Tags: sql

I want to select previous months column from a table. So for example: if the current month is April I want to select columns Jan, Feb and March. I tried using CASE but the problem with a one condition you can only select one column, and once the condition is matched then it will ignore subsequent when statements.

EDIT

Sample Data

| var_d | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

O/P for April

| var_d | Jan | Feb | Mar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Likewise in May we need April's data too

Comment: please provide some sample data and desired output

Comment: Have added sample data and desired output.

Comment: please show data as TEXT thank you

Comment: This will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34989510/dynamically-column-names-from-select-sql

Comment: If month is January should the total include October, November and December?

Comment: No it should include everything from previous year right from January to December, but let's not worry about that corner case yet...even it works till December it's fine.