# Use the result of a subquery as a column alias SQL

Tags: sql, subquery, alias, common-table-expression, lookup

I have a custom table (AccountCustom01F96D21_5134_4C7F_8EE9_C8070B6282B2) with many custom column names. I also have a lookup table (tblMetaData) where I can find the readable column label for these columns.
I want to write a query that selects all the columns from the custom table and aliases them as their simple names.
Ex. GUIDF5AFAD84_5319_4F54_978F_6E2A2AAD8F34 is equivalent to "Due Date".

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
WITH column1 as (SELECT b.FieldLabel FROM dbo.tblMetaData b WHERE 'GUIDF5AFAD84_5319_4F54_978F_6E2A2AAD8F34' = b.FieldName)
SELECT a.GUIDF5AFAD84_5319_4F54_978F_6E2A2AAD8F34 as column1
FROM collections.AccountCustom01F96D21_5134_4C7F_8EE9_C8070B6282B2 a, dbo.tblMetaData b;
```

^^ This just renames that column as column1 instead of the value of the subquery

```
SELECT a.GUIDF5AFAD84_5319_4F54_978F_6E2A2AAD8F34 as (SELECT b.FieldLabel FROM dbo.tblMetaData b WHERE 'GUIDF5AFAD84_5319_4F54_978F_6E2A2AAD8F34' = b.FieldName)
FROM collections.AccountCustom01F96D21_5134_4C7F_8EE9_C8070B6282B2 a, dbo.tblMetaData b;
```

^^ I get a syntax error with this

Comment: for that you must use dynamic sql like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34989510/dynamically-column-names-from-select-sql

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your CTE query returns one value for the column name, declare a variable with the result of that query being a string. Then use the variable as an alias.

Comment: no see my coment